# Difference between 也 and 者 as topic markers in Classical Chinese

Tags: classical-chinese

> 民之欲富貴也，共闔棺而後止。

> 曾子曰：「以能問於不能，以多問於寡；有若無，實若虛，犯而不校，昔者吾友嘗從事於斯矣。」

The first text uses 也 as a topic marker, and the second text uses 者 in the same way. What are the differences between these two? Are they fully interchangeable, from a grammatical perspective?

Comment: I think you are interested in knowing the difference between 也 and 矣. Please confirm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The use of 者 as what is called a nominaliser is [covered as standard](https://home.csulb.edu/%7Etxie/360/Etext/Lesson3/L3Grammar.htm) in introductory textbooks of Classical Chinese. 者 is thus usually considered very different to 也 in function, and the two are frequently used together [almost as if they were a set construction](https://press.rebus.community/guwen/chapter/lesson-13/) of the form A者B也.

Most relevant to this quote from the Analects 論語: the use of 昔者 and 古者 as *time expressions* is indeed very similar to 也, as stated in Pulleyblank's *Outline of Classical Chinese Grammar* ([p.74](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Outline_of_Classical_Chinese_Grammar/pM8QiZGImRgC?hl=en&gbpv=1&pg=PA74)). 今也 and 昔者 seem to be the collocations preferred in the 論語. But other combinations are attested elsewhere.

There is also the use of 也者, which has its own subtleties involving a certain kind of ['bare' noun or kind-denoting noun phrase](https://libstore.ugent.be/fulltxt/RUG01/002/862/806/RUG01-002862806_2020_0001_AC.pdf), and crops up occasionally in the 論語.

Answer (score 0):

"也", when used at the end of a sentence, equals to “啊” or “呀”.

"者" substitutes "person(人)", "thing/matter(事/物), and time(时) when combined with another word (noun, verb, adjective) to form a phrase.

- 昔者 = 昔时 = 昔日 = 過去 = 從前. "昔者吾友..." - "從前的老朋友..."

Answer (score 0):

> Are they fully interchangeable, from a grammatical perspective?

fully? **no** lah. only in some occasions, “者” could be read as “也”

the quoted texts in the question, if one change “者” to “也”, or vice versa; the texts need to rewrite, slightly, imo

for particles usages in classical chinese, two books are helpful:

[經傳釋詞](https://archive.org/search?query=%E7%B6%93%E5%82%B3%E9%87%8B%E8%A9%9E&sort=creator&and%5B%5D=mediatype%3A%22texts%22&not%5B%5D=collection%3A%22booksbylanguage%22) by 王引之

經詞衍釋 by 吳昌瑩

in 經傳釋詞 卷九, mentioned:

> **者**・猶**也**也

roughly means: [the particle] “者” [could be read] as “也” [in some occasions]

[image]

in 經傳釋詞 卷四, mentioned:

> 也・所以窮上成文也

roughly means: [the particle] “也”, is for ending preceding [text] (窮上), [and then] becoming [following] text (成文)

[image]

have fun :)

Answer (score 0):

Not that simple, both 也 and 者 can mean a host of different things in classical Chinese, depending on the context.

也 can be a filler (can be eliminated without loss in meaning), thus, etc. Examples: 故天降大任於斯人也；兵者，詭道也

者 can mean this, that, it, he, etc. Examples: 醫者父母心；昔有吳起者，母歿喪不臨